# Creating a form for nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models in an auction app. (This is technically with the mongoid gem but a plain rails answer is what I need, so just assume the field names are in the migrations not the model as in a regular rails app)

Model:

```
class Bid
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :amount
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :person
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :item, :person
end

class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  has_many :bids
end

class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :item_description
  has_many :bids
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :items do
  resources :bids
end

resources :people do
  resources :bids
end
```

I can create a nested form, as in the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/getting_started.html), for a single relationship like bid for supplier.

How and where (best practice/or easiest place) could I create a nested form to input a bid that `belongs_to` an item and a person?